# Counting Unique Values within a COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

have read a through a few questions that are similair to this but nothing quite the same as what I need.

I have a COUNTIFS formula with, at the moment, 4 criteria. The formula looks up a list of jobs and returns those that are

1. between a certain date (column N)
2. within a certain country (column A)
3. of a certain priority (column J)

   ```
    =COUNTIFS('DATA'!$N$2:$N$442,">=1/1/2022",'DATA'!$N$2:$N$442,"<4/1/2022",'DATA'!$A$2:$A$442,"UK",'DATA'!$J$2:$J$442,"High")
   ```

The problem I now have is, even after applying the criteria above, my source data still has duplicates. Deleting the duplicate rows is not an option as they are needed for other things.

I need to be able to add another clause that counts the UNIQUE job titles from column H. So for example, applying the above formula at the moments returns 5, when I want it to return 3.

```
    COUNTRY    START DATE    JOB TITLE    PRIORITY
    UK         01/01/2022    JOB 1        HIGH
    UK         01/01/2022    JOB 1        HIGH
    UK         01/01/2022    JOB 2        HIGH
    UK         01/01/2022    JOB 2        HIGH
    UK         01/01/2022    JOB 3        HIGH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

[image]

Formula in `F3`:

```
=SUM(--(LEN(UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C6,(B2:B6>=F1)*(B2:B6<=G1)*(A2:A6=H1)*(D2:D6=I1))))>0))
```

And if `COUNTIFS()` is a must (maybe due to Excel-version), then try:

```
=SUM(IF((B2:B6>=F1)*(B2:B6<=G1)*(A2:A6=H1)*(D2:D6=I1),1/COUNTIFS(B2:B6,">="&F1,B2:B6,"<="&G1,A2:A6,H1,D2:D6,I1,C2:C6,C2:C6),0))
```