# Excel: formula to count distinct (not unique) values within a date range (between two dates)

Tags: excel, date, conditional-statements, range, distinct

For simplicity I have two columns, one containing IDs/Names and the other one containing dates.

I would like to count the number of distinct IDs/Names between two dates. Example:

```
IDs_Names   Date
1234        01/01/2021
234a        01/01/2021
1234        15/01/2021
1234        01/02/2021
234a        15/01/2021
1478        31/03/2021
5987        01/01/2021
(blank)     01/01/2021
```

Assuming I want to know the distinct values within 01/01/2021 and 31/01/2021, I would expect results to be 3 (1234, 234a, 5987), blanks should be ignored.

Now ID_Names column is expected to be numeric, however, it would be great if we could keep this type flexible (as the input data may be formatted as text despite being a number).

I found in the web a formula that can count distinct values but not with additional conditions, i.e. a date range.

Thank you!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72270425/9758194) answer your question? If so, agreed to close this as a duplicate?

Comment: Hi @JvdV, thank you very much! Yes, that's what I am looking for. I found a lot of issues/answers on "unique", but they usually just ignore the ones that are double. Your answer and apparently the problem - although asking for counting unique ones only - is actually referring to my problem!